# FlexBox alignment issue in embedded span elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to align to the date time `span` element to the right. I can do that by using `float` property, but when I use flexbox I can't do that.

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot image]

---

**Code example:**

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #777;
}

.flex-container .secondText {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <span class="firstText">some text here..<span class="secondText">13:30</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `float` is the only way to do what you want, `flexbox` is not going to work here.

Comment: If `float: right;` does what you want cross-browser, why do you need another method for it?

Comment: Float attribute doesn't supported in ReactNative project. So I need to use flexbox

Comment: Does **[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54149601/4512005)** suit you?

Answer (score 4):

Let both `<span>` tags be `flex-items` (make them both immediate children of `<div class="flex-container"></div>`). Then add `margin-left: auto;` to the element you want to align to the *right*:

```css
.flex-container {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between; 
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1E79AA;
}

.flex-container .firstText {
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: justify; /* optional; text-align: right works too */
}

/* To avoid overlaping of time and plain text!!! */
.flex-container .firstText:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.flex-container .secondText {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  width: 40px;
  background: #FF9500;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <span class="firstText">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed massa orci, euismod elementum porttitor tempor, laoreet ut mauris. Aliquam feuaiat quam ac sem feuaiat hendrerit hendrerit feuaiat evoid overlap. </span>
  <span class="secondText">23:30</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. This solution is suit for me.. Actually I can't use ":after" class directly in  my ReatNative project. I guess be able to use this psuedo class  I need to install extra npm module..  Thanks to you anyway.. :)

Comment: @MLElyakan What I was writing about in my comment was **accepting**, not **voting**. You have to accept one of the answers you have received.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'll have multiple lines, if you want to wrap the text around the date, you'll have to use `float: right`, but if you don't mind placing the date over te rest of the text you can use `position: absolute` and place it at the bottom right corner.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #177CAB;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.flex-container .secondText {
  background-color: #E1B639;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <span class="firstText">
    some texrgrgt here.. soehme text here.. 
    someehtext here.. so wtwtg wtg rme text here..
    some text here.. some text here..
    <span class="secondText">13:30</span>
  </span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `flex` also to the outer span and use `justify-content: space-between;` on it, and `margin-left: auto` on the inner span to move it to the right. Now by default the inner span would be on the line below the last text line, but if you apply `margin-top: -1em;` to it, it is moved up:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #777;
  
}
.firstText {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }

.secondText {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: -1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <span class="firstText">some text here.. some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here some text here<span class="secondText">13:30</span></span>
</div>
```